# Capturing Enter Key press on windows form not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keypress

I have a user authentication form with username and password textboxes.There is an `okay` button that fires the code to validate the credentials.
I want the same code to get executed when the user hits `Enter` key anywhere on the form.
So i register for the keypress event like this

```
 this.KeyPress += UserLogin_KeyPress;
 private void UserLogin_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
             if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
                {
                MessageBox.Show("enter");
                }

        }
```

This event is not triggered at all.What i'm i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have KeyPreview enable?... Could you try with KeyDown event instead?   
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)

Comment: @GeraldoDiaz Tried,its also not working.

Comment: Is there a reason setting the [Form.AcceptButton Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Form_AcceptButton) is not a valid solution?

Comment: @TnTinMn Cool.I did not know about it.It works well.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the property keypreview to true and changing to keydown instead since KeyPress don't support e.Keycode:

```
private void UserLogin_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.Keydown is also not working.Welcome to SO.

Comment: Did you try     this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.frm_KeyPress); What about the keyPreview property in True?

Comment: setting keypreview to `true` and changing to keydown solved the issue.Could you please update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void UserLogin_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("enter");
   }
}
```

Comment: `'KeyPressEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyCode'`

Comment: Try to Set AcceptButton property to buttonName.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, set `form.KeyPreview = true` so that most key events will be given to the form before the controls.

However, note that this doesn't always work, and some controls will still "steal" certain key presses anyway. For example, if a `Button` has focus, then an Enter keypress will be used by the button to activate it, before you get a chance to see it, and since it counts as having been "handled", you never get to see the keypress.

The workaround I use for this is to set focus to something that I know will not steal the enter key press, for key presses that occur leading up to the enter key press. So, if the pressed keys are `<1><2><3><4><ENTER>` then the 1-4 keys all set focus to something that is not a button (usually, the textbox where I am displaying the resulting text), and then when `<ENTER>` is pressed, it should make it to your form's event handler (as long as `KeyPreview == true`).

Answer (score 0):

It's only looking at the form. *Controls* on the form also need to be wired in.

Comment: Please add details to your answer.